# Multiselect JavaScript library with quantity

Tags: library, javascript

Is there a js library that can do the following?

[image: desired behavior]

The library I'm using is [multiselect.js](http://loudev.com), but it doesn't allow the quantity select part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Syncfusion EJ2 ListView](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/listview) can meet this requirement. The quantity requirement has been added into this [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/TAczGvNSsNVXDhsFlURx?p=preview) application.

[image: EJ2 ListView with Quantity]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.